# Evaluating an intriguing expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Let $x_1,x_2...x_{2014} \in R, \not= 1$ such that $$x_1+x_2...+\ x_{2014}=1$$ and $$\frac{x_1}{1-x_1}+\frac{x_2}{1-x_2}...+\frac{x_{2014}}{1-x_{2014}}=1$$

---

$$\frac{x_1^2}{1-x_1}+\frac{x_2^2}{1-x_2}...+\frac{x_{2014}^2}{1-x_{2014}}= ?$$

---

Any solutions would be appreciated. I've been trying this for a while..but no breakthrough yet...

Comment: **Hint:**
$$\dfrac{x_1}{1-x_1} - x_1 = \dfrac{x_1 - x_1 + x_1^2}{1-x_1} = \dfrac{x_1^2}{1-x_1}$$

Comment: Sigh...How did I miss this? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Downvoter could you please explain?

Comment: Nice question! (+1) Where did it come from? And nice hint @DarthGeek! (+1).

Comment: @hypergeometric A competition requiring you to solve 100 problems in an hour. (Not an official competition of course... just a compendium of questions my friend and I pose to each other). He usually gets around 75 and me around 80 of these in the given time.. This particular occasion resulted in a draw! (83 each). But I didn't get this particular one (Hence I asked it here after the hour got over).

Comment: What a great idea - your own math olympiad duel!

Comment: Indeed similar I suppose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From comments:)

Notice that
$$
\frac{x}{1-x}-x=\frac{x-x+x^2}{1-x}=\frac{x^2}{1-x}
$$

So
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2014} \frac{x_i^2}{1-x_i}=\sum_{i=1}^{2014} \frac{x_i}{1-x_1}-\sum_{i=1}^{2014} x_i = 1-1 = 0
$$